# Facebook Ads API PHP: How to get the adaccounts of Custom Audience

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Can any one tell me the correct way of getting the ids of account which are sharing one Custom Audience i.e. adaccounts
**Query in PHP using API v2.4**

```
$account = new AdAccount($accountId);
    $fields = array(
        CustomAudienceFields::ID,
        CustomAudienceFields::NAME, 
        CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE,
        CustomAudienceFields::ACCOUNT_ID,
        CustomAudienceFields::ADACCOUNTS,
    );
    $params = array('filters'=>array(
                    array(
                        'field'=>'subtype',
                        'type'=>'in',
                        'value'=>['WEBSITE','CUSTOM'],
                    ),
                ),);    

    $CustomAudience = $account->getCustomAudiences($fields,$params);
```

**Results**

```
[adaccounts] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => 9.1432423423488E+14 [1] => 8.9623423402405E+14 [2] => 8.71252342345443E+14 [3] => 8.832242342342387E+14 [4] => 8.92234234079338E+14 ) )
```

**Note:** I added this property myself in CustomAudienceFileds.php:
"CustomAudienceFields::ADACCOUNTS"

**PROBLEM**
All values are in float or I don't know what these values are actually.
I converted these values to int but they appeared to be in negative and wrong account ids.
Please let me know what what and where I am wrong.

Its working absolutely fine in Graph Api Explorer tool when I Query this:
**Query in Graph Api Explorer v2.4:**
act_34234234234344/customaudiences?fields=adaccounts
**Results:**
 "adaccounts": {
        "data": [
          534534534534555,
          564563453454534,
          345345345345345,
          234234234234234
        ]
      }

Comment: It looks like your PHP isn't able to handle the 64 bit ints in the response - does it work with other responses from the API? Also, does it work with Facebook's main SDK or are you only trying with the 'ads' specific version?

Comment: I am using Facebook ads sdk. On other places I am fetching accounts ids (64 bit int) and they are displayed properly!!!

Comment: On what platform/OS? Does your install of PHP support 64 bit ints?

Comment: OS: Windows 7 64 bit and PHP 5.5.2. Thanks for your moral support lgy :) i found a workaround for this problem which i will write as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the values returned in response were in scientific notation, so simply iterated through each value(adaccountid) and convert it into integer using **spinrtf**, like this:

```
$i =0;
foreach ($CustomAudience as $audience) {
  foreach($audience->adaccounts['data'] as $accountid)
  {
    if($i ==0)
        $info["adaccountsIds"] =  sprintf('%.0F',$accountid);
    else
        $info["adaccountsIds"] .= ','.sprintf('%.0F',$accountid);

   $i++;
  }
}
```

**I will not say it answer, its a work around. Still more answers are welcome**